# No database selected mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have started to code with php and mysql and I am sort of confused, I have the mysql server setup and here is my code

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'mydatabase';
$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);
?>
```

and

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result === FALSE){
die(mysql_error());
 }
while($mytable = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<h3>" . $mytable['Name'] . "</h3>";
}
 ?>
```

I recieve the error "No database selected.", what's wrong with the code? D:

Comment: Try to use mysqli_ or PDO as mysql is depreciated and should not be used any more. Turn on error reporting, that shows you exactly where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any error n your code. Try the following codes and see if the error is still there.

connection.php:

```
 <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', '', 'mydatabase');
    ?>
```

and

```
 <?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if ($result === FALSE){
    die(mysqli_error());
     }
    while($mytable = mysqli_fetch_array($connection,$result)){
    echo "<h3>" . $mytable['Name'] . "</h3>";
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: http://puu.sh/cz63b/7feaf3f928.png is the errors I get and here is my user list http://puu.sh/cz65j/866ba0b8bc.png

Comment: Try changing user with root in the connection. That should remove all the errors.
`$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo mysql_error($connection);
```

right after the mysql_connect() line, and one after the mysql_db_select line()

you probably have some sort of error.

Comment: I get nothing on the page, leading me to believe it is not a connection error

Comment: are you sure connection.php is actally loaded? try changing include to required or add some echo's to the file